# How can I upgrade existing Office 2013 to Office 365

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, license

I have Office 2013 installed and configured and use it for everything including email.

How can I switch the license over to an Office 365 license? Is it possible or do I need to reinstall everything with the Office 365 installer?

Answer (score 1):

Asked MS support and they told me that you have to uninstall Office 2013 and reinstall Office 365 since they are two different suites